# Angular Reactive Forms: How to access form control names with in a group without knowing it's key in HTML

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive angular forms to build my form and below is the function that adds a nested form group within the main form group. The nested form group has from controls based on the params being sent.

The form group is building correctly.

My problem:

If it's a pre-defined set of keys defined within the form group, we can access it from HTML form by using formControlName = 'key' but in my case, since I don't know the form control reference key ahead of time, I am not sure how to refer to the form controls in the HTML.

.ts file

Form Model Function:

```
    buildForm(type:string, params: {name: string,required: boolean}[]) {
          let pathParamFormGroup: FormGroup;
          let formControls = {};

          params.forEach((param: {name: string,required: boolean}) => {
              const {name, required} = param;
              formControls[name] = new FormControl('', required ? Validators.required: null);
          });

          pathParamFormGroup = new FormGroup(formControls);
          this.form.addControl(type, pathParamFromGroup);
    }
```

html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="sendRequest()" [formGroup]="requestForm"> 
  <ng-container formGroupName="query">
    <input formControlName="????" type="text"> --> Not sure how to get the form control names within a form group in html. 
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*ngFor` to iterate directly through your `formGroup`'s `controls` property to reach the form controls.

Look at this example what I made on stackblitz:

[*ngFor With formGroup](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k68u5i)